# This seems to be an error in the book C++ Primer 5th edition

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, reference

The following is an excerpt from the book C++ Primer 5th edition (emphasis is mine):

> A nontype parameter may be an integral type, or a pointer or (lvalue)
>   reference to an object or to a function type. An argument bound to a
>   nontype integral parameter must be a constant expression. **Arguments
>   bound to a pointer or reference nontype parameter must have static
>   lifetime** (Chapter 12, p. 450). We may not use an ordinary (nonstatic)
>   local object or a dynamic object as a template argument for reference
>   or pointer nontype template parameters. A pointer parameter can also
>   be instantiated by nullptr or a zero-valued constant expression.

Right below this paragraph one can find this highlighted Note:

> Template arguments used for nontype template parameters must be
>   constant expressions.

Maybe I'm missing something, but I believe the Note is wrong, as nontype template parameters of a pointer or lvalue reference to an object or function type are not constant expressions.

Comment: *Maybe I'm missing something* Yes, `const` etc. ...  There is no reason why a pointer can't be hardcoded to one function etc.

Comment: What do you mean by _"nontype template parameters of a pointer or lvalue reference to an object or function type are not constant expressions"_ They may be both const and non-const expressions, depending how you declare/define them. To use them as template non type parameter you MUST have them as const expressions

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're concerned about doing `foo<&obj>`. However, the quotation you posted addresses that: *Arguments bound to a pointer or reference nontype parameter must have static lifetime*

Comment: @chris Can a pointer to a static object be considered a constant expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are worried about non-type pointer below you have perfectly valid  specialization of a structure with non-type pointer to function template parameter:

```
void foo() { }

template <void(*)()>
struct bar { };

int main() {
   bar<&foo> b; 
}
```

The `&foo` here is also a constant expression as it has a static lifetime.

As Revolver_Ocelot mentioned 5.20[expr.const] /5 and 5.2 states it clearly:

> A constant expression is either a glvalue core constant expression
>   whose value refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a
>   constant expression (as defined below), or a prvalue core constant
>   expression whose value is an object where, for that object and its
>   subobjects:
>
> (...)
>
> - if the object or subobject is of pointer type, it contains the address of an object with static storage duration, the address past
>     the end of such an object (5.7), the address of a function, or a null
>     pointer value

(I used draft N4296)

Comment: `The &foo here is also a constant expression as it has static lifetime.` Could you point to a quote in the Standard confirming this, i.e., that `&foo` is a constant expression?

Comment: @JohnKalane 14.3.2/1 [temp.arg.nontype]

Comment: @JohnKalane also 5.19/4  [expr.const]

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot almost got there... Thanks :)